# Crestal report to show on full screen

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, crystal-reports

I am implementing the crystal report in MVC. But it shows on the small screen and some options are missing on the interface. anyone can help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaAji.png)

The above is the image of the crystal which actually looks like on my machine but i want it on full with full options.

Comment: Could you share the code you use to create and display the Crystal Reports objects?